# Docker - Unable to Access Service from Localhost

Tags: docker

I've created a Dockerfile which looks like this:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk

COPY . .
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/graphdb"]

EXPOSE 7200
```

On doing `docker run 34a1650b461d -p 127.0.0.1:7200:7200` I see my service running as shown in the terminal output - however when I go to `localhost:7200` I keep seeing `This site can’t be reached 127.0.0.1 refused to connect.`

Could anyone explain what I'm missing?

Also fyi - when I do `docker ps`, under `PORTS` I see `7200/tcp`.

I read [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30109037/how-can-i-forward-localhost-port-on-my-container-to-localhost-on-my-host) and followed what was described but to no luck.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `docker run` the order of the parameters matter, so this:

```
docker run 34a1650b461d -p 7200:7200
```

Is not the same as:

```
docker run -p 7200:7200 34a1650b461d
```

In the first case you are passing the parameters `-p 7200:7200` to your `ENTRYPOINT` command `/bin/graphdb`; whereas in the second case, you are passing `-p 7200:7200` to `docker run`, which is what you wanted.

## How to validate when ports are correctly forwarded?

You can validate this by running `docker ps` and checking the `PORTS` column:

```
$ docker run -d 34a1650b461d -p 7200:7200
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
03abc0b390ef        mytest              "/bin/graphdb -p 720…"   6 seconds ago       Up 5 seconds        7200/tcp            elegant_wescoff
```

Do you see how the `COMMAND` includes your `-p`? That's not what you wanted. So `docker run` was not interpreting that parameter at all. Also, you can see the `PORTS` column, which shows the port is exposed but not forwarded.

Whereas doing it like this:

```
$ docker run -d -p 7200:7200 34a1650b461d
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                             NAMES
03abc0b390ef        mytest              "/bin/graphdb"           6 seconds ago       Up 5 seconds        0.0.0.0:7200->7200/tcp            elegant_wescoff
```

You can see now that `-p` is not being passed to `COMMAND` and that the port is forwarded: `0.0.0.0:7200->7200/tcp`.

Comment: Ah! Thats great - works. Thanks very much for pointing that out. I won't forget anytime soon :p